# Running VPN Software as non administrative user in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn, administrator

I have several laptops in the field all using windows 10 for an OS. All users are normal user accounts no admin rights. The issue I have is that these users now need a VPN. I have installed OpenVPN on the machines, but unless I run the program as administrator it doesn't set up the tunnels correctly. It looks like it's connected but it hasn't, and the user is unable to access the end program via the VPN. I really don't want to have to make these users admins or give them any admin credentials for the machines other accounts.

The issue here isn't the VPN software.

It's the associated tunnels that fail to set themselves up. Using the answer provided in this question:

[OpenVPN client without administrator rights on Win7](https://superuser.com/questions/505204/openvpn-client-without-administrator-rights-on-win7)

will get OpenVPN up and running, but it will fail to open the routes as shown below

```
Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 ROUTE: route addition failed using CreateIpForwardEntry: Access is denied.   [status=5 if_index=4]

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 Route addition fallback to route.exe

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 ERROR: Windows route add command failed [adaptive]: returned error code 1

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 C:\windows\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.0.2.209

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 ROUTE: route addition failed using CreateIpForwardEntry: Access is denied.   [status=5 if_index=9]

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 Route addition fallback to route.exe

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 ERROR: Windows route add command failed [adaptive]: returned error code 1

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 C:\windows\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.0.2.209

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 ROUTE: route addition failed using CreateIpForwardEntry: Access is denied.   [status=5 if_index=9]

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 Route addition fallback to route.exe

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 ERROR: Windows route add command failed [adaptive]: returned error code 1

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1476284290,ADD_ROUTES,,,

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 C:\windows\system32\route.exe ADD 10.0.0.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.0.2.209

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 ROUTE: route addition failed using CreateIpForwardEntry: Access is denied.   [status=5 if_index=9]

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 Route addition fallback to route.exe

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem

Wed Oct 12 15:58:10 2016 ERROR: Windows route add command failed [adaptive]: returned error code 1
```

Again, if I run the program as administrator and enter admin credentials these errors don't occur; the routes are created with no errors.

Comment: http://openvpn.se/files/howto/openvpn-howto_run_openvpn_as_nonadmin.html

Comment: Please see question edits above, hopefully this should remove the duplicate tag from the question as this is now more specfically to do with the routes rather than the software

Comment: I'm not sure how that makes it any different of a question. From the duplicate question "The problem is they cannot start the client without admin privileges, since the route cannot be added to the system without."  Adding routes IS the problem, you need to be an admin to add them, and it's why OpenVPN wants/needs Admin privileges.  The answers on the other question apply equally here as well.  But hey, request it be reopened if you'd like, and others can decide.

Comment: well, the above edits are showing the failures after following the steps in the suggested answer. I think this is a solution that worked up until W10 but no longer works now as we dont have this issue with the devices running W7.

Comment: Rule 1 of SE duplicates: just because an accepted answer doesn't work, doesn't mean you should just post the exact same question again.  you should edit your questing to spell out exactly how it's different, and what you've done/tried already so that the people reading it know...  Anyhow, so now it seems you're saying you set it up as a service (based on the one answer in the other question).., if so, you should edit your question to specify that.  If that IS what you did which/what kind of user is the service running as?

Comment: Even if this question isn't a duplicate, it seems like it might belong on [SF].

Comment: Techie, your right, sorry I was trying to find a rush answer last thing yesterday. I have a fresh device to test this with today so I will spend some more time with this today and either edit the post to be different or just add to the existing post.